# Cannot get block element to shift up into row above

Tags: css, html, block

I'm a beginner with HTML and CSS, and I'm making a site for a friend. On this page http://mypersonalcredo.com/categories.php I can't get that last "Coming Soon" photo to shift up into the row above. I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be great and thank you!

Comment: You’ve got some severe problems in your markup, by the way — you’ve got some “tags” like this: `<style="font-size:20px">`. This is *terribly wrong*…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy fix: replace `float:left;` with `display:inline-block;` on your `category` class.

You may want to use `vertical-align:top;` as well to align the upper sides of all pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `<br>` after the "Wear What You Believe In!" text. inside `.catdesc` related to the t-shirt div.
It should fix it.

To see what is causing the issue you can open the developer console and then inspect the "Wear What You Believe In!" text . Remove the `<br>` element selecting it and pressing the DELETE button.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add:

```
clear: left;
```

to the ones that are stuck on the right and they will go to the far left underneath. I added it to that div for the "Cards". Check out the screenshot below:

[image]

It also may help for you to read more about using clears and floats.

Check out this article: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

This is because your image with the shirt is to large with the extra text undeneath and is making the floating elements push each other down. See image for example. To fix you will have to make it take up equal amount of space as the other category elements [image]

Comment: Actually it’s more because of that one line “Wear What You Believe In!” that not every box has.

Comment: Yes, because there is a <br> added after that text.